# Fixing a SyntaxError. Trying to select multiple rows and columns from a pandas DataFrame when column name is "Operation short text"

Tags: python, pandas

```py
In [106]:

anal = cleandata[cleandata.Operation short text=='Analytical Lab']
```

> File "", line 1
>      anal = cleandata[cleandata.Operation short text=='Analytical Lab']
>                                          ^
>    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You can't use attribute notation for something that's not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide any description of your DataFrame,
it is not obvious what is wrong, but I suppose that:

- One of columns in your DataFrame (*cleandata*) has name *Operation short text*.
- You want to print rows where this column *== 'Analytical Lab'*.

In this case (column name containing spaces) you can not use "dot notation"
(*df_name.col_name*). Use notation *df_name['col_name']* instead (the column
name as a **string**, between brackets):

```
anal = cleandata[cleandata['Operation short text'] == 'Analytical Lab']
```